# Finding the expectation of $\operatorname{E}(z^X)$ with $X\sim\operatorname{Binom}(n,p)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If $X$ has a binomial distribution with paramters $n$ and $p$. How do you find the expectation of $\operatorname{E}(z^X)$ where $z$ is any real number.

My guess would be that it is equal to $z^{pn}$ but the answer is $(pz + 1-p)^n$.

Can someone explain this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$ \mathbb{E}(z^X) = \sum_{k=0}^n z^k\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}  $$
It's because when $\varphi$ is a Borel function, and the distribution is discrete $(x_i, p_i)$, then:

$$\mathbb{E}(\varphi(X)) = \sum_{i\in I} \varphi(x_i)p_i $$

Our $I$ is $\{0, 1, \dots, n\}$, $\varphi(x)$ is $z^x$, $i$ is $k$ here, and our $p_i$ is $\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$